# How to get active tabs in pycharm community edition?

Tags: pycharm

I am using pycharm community edition 2019.1 version. It is not showing active tabs at the top, instead showing only current working tab. 
How to get all active tabs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Goto Window -> Editor Tabs -> Tabs Placement` and select where you want active tabs to be shown [top, bottom etc...]

Comment: Wow, it worked. Tqsm:)